# get a 2D bounding box from a 3D object

Tags: three.js, 2d, bounding-box

I have a scene filled with ~hundred oblong asteroid shaped objects.  I want to place a text label under each one so that the label is visible from any camera angle.  I billboard the text so that it always faces the camera.

At first, everything looks great by placing text below the 3d object using `.translateY`.  However, as you start to moving around the scene, labels no longer are 'below' the object depending on your camera position.  This especially true when you orient using trackballControls.

How can I place text 'below' the object no matter the orientation.  Perhaps if I create a 2d bounding box around each object in relation to the camera on each frame - I could then place the text label right below that 2d box.

I'm also concerned that calculating 2d bounding boxes on a hundred 3d objects every frame could get expensive.  Thoughts?

screenshots:

At first, text labels appear correctly translated -y below the object
[image]

but as you rotate the camera, labels get sideways
[image]

flipping the camera all the way around shows the labels upside down
[image]

**My goal is to have the labels below the objects no matter the camera orientation.**

Comment: Consider using CSS for your text. See, for example, http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_pdb.html.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add the Text Labels to the Object?

object.add(Label) instead of scene.add(Label)

Comment: yeah, I'll post a screenshot of what's going on.  Hard to describe 3d scenes without visuals.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo site here that might help give you source to look at:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31495717/cubemaker/index.html

This site places textual DOM elements at a screen coordinate-based constant distance from a 3D object, styled with CSS, within the render loop, when the mouse pointer is moved over the 3D object.

From the source:

```
var id_label = document.createElement('div');
id_label.id = INTERSECTED.name;
id_label.style.position = 'absolute';
id_label.style.top = '-10000px';
id_label.style.left = '-10000px';
id_label.innerHTML = '<span class="particle_label">' + INTERSECTED.name + '<br><span class="particle_sublabel">' + INTERSECTED.subname + '</span></span>';
container.appendChild(id_label);
var id_label_rect = id_label.getBoundingClientRect();
id_label.style.top = (screen_object_center.y - 0.85 * (id_label_rect.height / 2)) + 'px';
if (mouse.x < 0)
    id_label.style.left = (screen_object_center.x - horizontal_fudge * (screen_object_edge.x - screen_object_center.x)) + 'px';
else {
    id_label.style.left = (screen_object_center.x + horizontal_fudge * (screen_object_edge.x - screen_object_center.x) - id_label_rect.width) + 'px';
    id_label.style.textAlign = 'right';
}
```

The DOM element is drawn offscreen and then repositioned based on attributes of its bounding box and the world coordinates of the 3D element it is associated with. When the mouse pointer is moved outside the 3D element bounds, the text label is removed from the DOM.

Since you are always showing your labels, you might modify this to draw the element once in an initialization step, and simply change the `top` and `left` style attributes within the render loop.

Comment: pretty neat.  I'll give this a whirl and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for sharing

Comment: I'm just learning three.js, so I don't know how well this scales, as far as number of labels. If you put this approach through its paces, I'd be curious to know what problems you run into, if any.